# how to know from which class instance a function is called to access the instance attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes

I want to access an attribute of the class instance that called a function :

for example:

```
class A:
    def a(self):
        return B.q

class B:
    q=0
    def b(self):
        M=A()
        return M.a()
c=B()

c.q = 6

print(c.b())
```

the output will be `0` but I want it to print the `q` attribute of the instance `c` of the class `B` which has the value `6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the instance as a parameter.

```
class A:
    def a(self, b):
        return b.q

class B:
    q=0
    def b(self):
        M=A()
        return M.a(self)
c=B()

c.q = 6

print(c.b())
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be *very* bad program design.  What are you trying to accomplish with this?

1. You have a class attribute and an instance attribute -- in that class -- of the same name, `q`.  This makes your code difficult to follow and to maintain.
2. You have method B.b instantiate an instance of class A.  You immediately call A.a, which has been assigned the questionable task of returning an instance attribute from and object of class B.

Clean up your design.

- Use **init** appropriately for each class.
- Design your class methods to work appropriately with the characteristics of instances *of that class*.  Your question strongly suggests that your design is not yet clean in your mind, nor in code.

Answer (score 0):

define an init method so that you can work with the instance attributes instead of the class variable

```py
class A:
    def a(self):
        return B.q

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = 0

    def b(self):
        M=A()
        return M.a()
c=B()

c.q = 6

print(c.b())
```